# How split a URL string containing multiple '&'

Tags: python, string, split

I'm using Python to split a string so that its results form a list.

String example:

```
text = 'https://a.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3&https://b.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3'
# It uses '&' to separate multiple URLs. How should I get them out?
# What I need is
URL_list = ['https://a.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3','https://b.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3']
```

I tried to use str.split() and re.split(), but I didn't get the desired result.
Maybe my method is wrong, but what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), splitting on an `&` that is followed by `http://` or `https://` (checking using a forward lookahead so as not to absorb those characters):

```py
import re
text = 'https://a.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3&https://b.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3'
re.split(r'&(?=https?://)', text)
```

Output:

```
['https://a.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3', 'https://b.com/api?a=1&b=2&c&c=3']
```